# I don't know why this makefile gives error

Tags: makefile

I have a `test.c` file with basic content:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm trying to create a makefile that identifies the operating system and compiles the code to a directory named `bin` . Here is the makefile:

```
CCunix=clang
CCwin = icx
name=test
files=$(name).c

OSFLAG              :=
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    OSFLAG+=win
else
    OSFLAG+=unix
endif

all:
ifeq ($(OSFLAG), win)
ifeq ($(CCwin), icx)
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat" intel64
endif
    @if not exist "bin\" mkdir bin
    @$(CCwin) $(files) -o bin\$(name)
else
    @mkdir -p bin
    @$(CCunix) $(files) -o bin/$(name)
endif

clean_bin:
ifeq ($(OSFLAG), win)
    @del /Q bin
else
    @rm -r bin
endif
```

when I run `make` on `windows` it gives the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, icx test.c -o bin\test, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [makefile:18: all] Error 2
```

I don't know why it stops at line 19. What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the original answer was posted from ChatGPT (it looks like to me) and was deleted (ChatGPT answers are not acceptable on SO).  Anyway, that answer didn't actually answer the question, although one of the comments made later was correct.

Each (logical) line in a make recipe is invoked in a separate shell, so you can't set variables in one line and have them visible on a different logical line.

You can either (a) run the setvars script before starting make, (b) have make re-invoke itself recursively (this is very tricky however), or (c) put the setvars on the same line as the compile; that could look something like this, for Windows cmd.exe (note the `&&` at the end of the `SETVARS` line):

```
ifeq ($(OSFLAG)/$(CCwin),win/icx)
SETVARS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat" intel64 &&
else
SETVARS =
endif

all:
ifeq ($(OSFLAG), win)
        @if not exist "bin\" mkdir bin
        @$(SETVARS) $(CCwin) $(files) -o bin\$(name)
else
        @mkdir -p bin
        @$(CCunix) $(files) -o bin/$(name)
endif
```